# Shortcut and bar code scanner

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, barcode-scanner

In my WPF Application I have a menu. One of the option from that menu has a shortcut assigned: <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd>. In my application I also need a possibility to scan a bar code using bar code scanner. 
My bar code is configured in a way where <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> combination is used to specify the bar code starting point. In other words: Bar code scanner sends <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> combination to tell me: "Hey I now starting to send you the bar code numbers".

I listening for the bar code input on `Window_PreviewKeyDown` event handler. This however does not work because firstly, application recognizes that <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> was pressed and wants to call the command's executed method associated with the shortcut <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd>. Is there a way to have a solution for this issue without changing the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

You may change the barcode scanner configuration to send some other keys at start.
Most barcode scanners provide a configuration manual where you can set such settings.

Please note that handling specific characters from barcode scanners can cause some trouble when the user changes his scanner or you have multiple users using different scanners.

Comment: yes I know that, however I cannot suggest users to change their bar code scanner configuration. There are to many of them so this is not the case.